# Pie Chart in Windows Universal 10

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, pie-chart, windows-10-mobile

I'm currently working with a `Windows Universal 10 Mobile App`.

I want to draw a Pie Chart.. But I can't find any Chart Control..

Any suggestion to draw a Chart in Windows 10 Universal App?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install WinRT XAML Toolkit - Data Visualization Controls for Windows 10 from Nuget Run the following command in the Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.UWP
```

Then, add the namespace in your XAML files that you need to implement chart control:

```
xmlns:Charting="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting"
```

Now, you can use chart controls:

For example, I draw a PieChart

```
<Charting:Chart 
    x:Name="PieChart" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Margin="0" > 
    <Charting:PieSeries Margin="0" 
         IndependentValuePath="Name" 
         DependentValuePath="Amount" 
         IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
</Charting:Chart>
```

In my .cs file:

Add namespace:

```
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
public class FinancialStuff
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadChartContents();
}

private void LoadChartContents()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    List<FinancialStuff> financialStuffList = new List<FinancialStuff>();
    financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "MSFT", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
    financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "AAPL", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
    financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "GOOG", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
    financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "BBRY", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
    (PieChart.Series[0] as PieSeries).ItemsSource = financialStuffList;
    (ColumnChart.Series[0] as ColumnSeries).ItemsSource = financialStuffList;
    (LineChart.Series[0] as LineSeries).ItemsSource = financialStuffList;
}
```

You can follow this tutorial(Windows 8.1) 
[USING GRAPHS AND CHARTS](http://eren.ws/2013/10/15/using-graphs-and-charts-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-11/)

Comment: How would I implement this chart in a dialog box without using Xaml?
I'd like to implement it in C# code only. In a UWP app

Answer (score 3):

Syncfusion provides free license to independent developers for their Essential Studio suite. They have some great visualization tools. You can check them here: https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp

You can find more information about its free license at following link: https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

And Filip Skakun has made a great library that has several charting options available! It has been possible to use it in WinRT and he is in the works on porting it to UWP ( Win 10 ).

The links you can follow to get more info

https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit ( the complete lib ) https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Shared/Charting ( charting part )

Comment: How can I use SyncFunction? It's only free 30 days??

Comment: go to [https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) and click on `Claim Free License` button.